# The space $L_{loc}^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I read in some references that for $p$ integer

$ L_{loc}^{p}(\mathbb{R}^+) =\{ f : \mathbb{R^+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ \; \text{wher}  \; \forall \;\Omega\;  \text{ compact of} \; \mathbb{R}^+ \;  f \in L^p(\Omega)  \}$

so is it the same definition for $ L_{loc}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ ?

and does this space have some propreties of convergence or boundedness for its function ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can define it, but I've never heard of any good use for it.

Comment: i heard it calle space of locally bounded functions ?

Comment: Sure, that's right (or at least locally essentially bounded functions). But it doesn't have much in the way of nice properties by itself. It might have nicer properties when intersected with other spaces, like $L^p \cap L^\infty_{loc}$ or similar.